# django - how to sort objects alphabetically by first letter of name field

Tags: python, django

I have a model which has the fields `word` and `definition`. model of dictionary.

in db, i have for example these objects:

```
word          definition
-------------------------
Banana        Fruit
Apple         also Fruit
Coffee        drink
```

I want to make a query which gives me, sorting by the first letter of word, this:

```
Apple - also Fruit
Banana - Fruit    
Coffee -drink
```

this is my model:

```
class Wiki(models.Model):
   word = models.TextField() 
   definition = models.TextField()
```

I want to make it in views, not in template. how is this possible in django?

Comment: Something like `MyModel.objects.order_by('word')`?

Comment: In what way does it not work?

Comment: @doniyor This can't be true.

Comment: Could happen if you have a wacky DB collation. You'll have to give more info about the DB backend and the exact data you're using.

Comment: @doniyor Which DB are you using? MySQL?

Comment: @doniyor So you have it working now?

Comment: @doniyor Added answer with a bit more info.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Given the model...

```
class Wiki(models.Model):
   word = models.TextField() 
   definition = models.TextField()
```

...the code...

```
my_words = Wiki.objects.order_by('word')
```

...should return the records in the correct order.

However, you won't be able to create an index on the `word` field if the type is `TextField`, so sorting by `word` will take a long time if there are a lot of rows in your table.

I'd suggest changing it to...

```
class Wiki(models.Model):
   word = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True) 
   definition = models.TextField()
```

...which will not only create an index on the `word` column, but also ensure you can't define the same word twice.

Answer (score 8):

Since you tagged your question Django, I will answer how to do it using Django entities.

First, define your entity like:

```
class FruitWords(models.Model):
    word = models.StringField()
    definition = models.StringField()

    def __str__(self):
        return "%s - %s" % (self.word, self.definition)
```

To get the list:

```
for fruit in FruitWords.all_objects.order_by("word"):
    print str(fruit)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using class based ListView

```
class WikiListView(ListView):
        model = Wiki
        template_name = # Path to your html code. Example: 'appName/htmlFileName.html

        def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
            wiki_list = Wiki.objects.order_by('word')
            context = super(WikiListView, self).get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
            context["wiki_list"] = wiki_list
            return context
```

---

if you are using a simple view

```
def WikiView(request):
    wiki_list = Wiki.objects.order_by('word')
    return render(request, """HTML File""", {'wiki_list': wiki_list})
```

Answer (score 0):

for example, I have an `Article` object that have a `title` field.

```py
articles = list(sorted(articles, key=lambda obj:obj.title))
```

the issue you may run into is that you must require to return a `QuerySet` in class method occasions like `get_queryset`, the solution is stopping using a class based view and switch to a function view.